# Why is my regex matching ending square bracket

Tags: regex

I need to match `foo1` in following text `[@foo1]`.

So Im using this regex `@([A-z0-9]*)`.

The problem is, it also matches the ending square bracket so I get `foo1]` as result.

[image: regex101.com example]

So the **questions** are:

- Why is the ending square bracket included in the result?
- How do I write regex to match only `foo1`

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote if the answer wasn't obvious. I wasn't able to search for any similar post. Actually, the answers may be duplicate, but the question is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `A-Za-z0-9` was required..

Thinking about ASCII or whatever encoding is used. I bet ] lies within A-z!

See [here using the above regex](https://regex101.com/r/baDbFH/2)

Yup.. 93 according to [this](http://www.asciitable.com/)

If you allowed `_`, too - you would have been able to use `\w*`

Answer (score 0):

You've specified `A-z`. Let's look at an ASCII chart:

[image]

`A` is 41 hex, and `z` is 7A hex, and in between them at 5D hex is `]`. That's why the `]` is included in the match - because that's what you asked it to do.

You might want to try `@([A-Za-z0-9]+)` instead.

Comment: Already given that!

Comment: and there's a difference between + and * - former is 1+ latter 0+